# ASP.NET 4 bundles and WebResource.axd

Tags: asp.net, webresource.axd

ASP.NET 4 includes a great bundling and compressing feature. I wonder if we can somehow use it together with WebResource.axd.

Right now, I can register a resource for my application using

```
[assembly: WebResource("MvcApplication1.Bootstrap.js", "text/javascript", PerformSubstitution = true)]
```

and when I've tried few combinations that using a path for a bundle - it just won't include it, which sounds rational because web resources are actual files which is embedded in the library. but sill I wish to make sure that I'm not missing anything.

Is there a way to combine bundles with web resource?